# React - Best methot to increase counter when button is increased and render result in another page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, client-server

I'm super new to the React and Javascript world and trying to throw myself into some development by making a Magic 8 Ball application.

I've got two pages set up:

1. The magic 8 ball game page
2. A stats page to display info about the magic 8 ball questions

The game page functionality works (using the snippet in server.js file below), but I now want to pass information from the game page to the stats page on the total number of questions asked.

My basic idea is:

- When the button is clicked, I want to increase the counter by 1
- Store this counter value in local storage and return in the stats page (simply want to print it for now)

I've come across a few different methods, but just need a bit of guidance on the best approaches to take.

A few snippets of what I've put together so far before implementing this:

**index.js file**

```
<form className="question-input" method="POST" action="/">
  <input type="text" ref="inputquestion" placeholder="Ask your question..."style={{ width: "300px", fontSize:18 }}/>
  <button id="submitquestion" style={{ width: "100px", fontSize:17 }}>Shake Me!</button>
</form>
```

**server.js file**

```
  server.post('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log("Received request.")
    const answers = [
      "It is certain.",
      "It is decidedly so.",
      "Without a doubt.",
      "Yes - definitely.",
      "You may rely on it.",
      "As I see it, yes.",
      "Most likely.",
      "Outlook good.",
      "Yes.",
      "Signs point to yes.",
      "Reply hazy, try again.",
      "Ask again later.",
      "Better not tell you now.",
      "Cannot predict now.",
      "Concentrate and ask again.",
      "Don't count on it.",
      "My reply is no.",
      "My sources say no.",
      "Outlook not so good.",
      "Very doubtful."
    ]
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
    res.status(200).send(answers[number]);
```

**stats.js file**

```
class StatsPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header />
          <h1>Game Statistics</h1>
          <p> Count: </p>
          <style jsx>{`
            h1 {
              font-family:"Arial";
              font-size:50px;
            }`}
          </style>

      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default StatsPage;
```

My question is: how can I render a counter variable in stats.js each time the button is pressed (i.e. a question is asked) in the index.js file? Should I be using saveToLocalStorage to ensure the counter remains saved to its state and isn't reverted to zero each time the application is refreshed?

Also - if anyone has any improvement comments, please do share!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to React and JavaScript, it would be best to use localStorage for this. It's the least complex solution to the problem, and is a good way to stop your applications state disappearing whenever you refresh your browser.

State like this that needs to be shared across pages could be held in a parent component that wraps the two page components. The parent component can then pass the state to the child components as props. This parent component could also try to load its initial state from localStorage when it mounts (see [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)), and handle writing the state to localStorage.

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminparnell/k8baL709/) with a very simplified example of what I describe above.

As a side note, I see your handling your form submission using the `action` attribute. This will cause your page to refresh, which might not be what you want. A React way of handling this would be using the `onSubmit` prop of `<form>`. See the [examples in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: Regarding the onSubmit, am I on the right lines here? This doesn't seem to be posting as the action attribute did.
onSubmit function: 
  `handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('RECEIVED.');
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST'
      }
    )
  }`
Form: 
`<form className="question-input" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: Checked out the example - is it the same case of using {props.count} when dealing with two separate files? i.e. two different classes as opposed to just components?

Comment: You are on the right lines with your onSubmit yes. I would check out the network tab in your developer tools and see what the request is sending back, to make sure the request is doing what you expect. You'll want to use the `.then` part of Promises to capture the result of what your fetch returns. 

`fetch('/', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => console.log(response))`

The approach for passing state would be the same for two class components as well yes.